# How to pass emoji scraping a text in phyton with bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup, emoji, scrape

I'm creating a scraper that scrapes all the comments in a URL page and I'm saving the text in a txt file (1 comment = 1 txt).
Now I'm having a problem when there are some emoji in the text of a comment. In fact, the program stops and says "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode the character". How can I pass this problem? (I'm using bs4)

The structure of the code is like this:

```
q=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(q.content, "html.parser")
x=soup.find("a",  {"class":"comments"})
y=x.find_all("div", {"class":"blabla"})
i=0
for item in y: 
    name=str(i)
    comment=item.find_all("p")
    out_file=open('%s.txt'%CreatorName, "w")          
    out_file.write(str(comment)
    out_file.close
    i=i+1
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: out_file=open('%s.txt'%name, "w")

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are on Windows. You code works perfectly on Linux. So change the encoding on the file you open to utf-8 like this:

```
out_file=open('%s.txt'%CreatorName, "w", encoding='utf-8')
```

This should write to the file without error although the emoji may not display properly in notepad you can always open it in FireFox or another application if you want to see the emoji. Other comment text should be readable in notepad though.